# USB connection failure on winxp desktop

Tags: windows-xp, usb

There's a USB interface that can connect some USB sticks but can't connect others. The error message is needing 'ksudbus.sys'. How to resolve this?

Comment: What's different about the working & non-working usb devices (sticks)? Anything? And what exactly is the error message? Windows/linux/macos & what version?

Comment: It looks like some sticks are flagged for file system check, some don't. Did you research what is ksudbus.sys and how it is possible related to file system check?

Comment: absolutely no clue from my side

Comment: @Xen2050 error msg is needing 'ksudbus.sys'. the usb interface can connect some usb sticks, some phones.

Comment: @Ale..chenski error msg is needing 'ksudbus.sys'. the usb interface can connect some usb sticks, some phones.

Comment: I repeat my question: did you try to research what the "ksudbus.sys" is? Doesn't it bother you that it is linked to some Chinese malware company?

Comment: @Ale..chenski yes i did. have no idea what that is though. can't download this file from anywhere. do you think it's a virus?

Comment: This driver seems to be a part of some shoddy "recovery software". It looks like some of your USB sticks are contaminated. Reformat these sticks with some raw-level tools and forget about the ksudbus, and better move to at least Win7.